# How to compare two XML files and display the differences in html format using Ruby

Tags: ruby, xml, nokogiri

I have a range of xml files stored on my PC. I stored the content of these files using the gem Nokogiri. I need to compare the content of these xmls two at a time. If there are differences between the xml files, I would like to display these differences in a pretty html report for others to view.

Does anyone know how this can be done?

First xml file I am comparing:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SourceDetails>
    <Origin>Origin</Origin>
    <Identifier>Identifier</Identifier>
    <Timestamp>2001-12-31T12:00:00</Timestamp>
  </SourceDetails>
  <AsOfDate>2001-01-01</AsOfDate>
  <Instrument>
    <ASXExchangeSecurityIdentifier>ASX</ASXExchangeSecurityIdentifier>
  </Instrument>
  <Rate>0.0</Rate>
```

Second xml file I am comparing:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SourceDetails>
        <Origin>FEED</Origin>
        <Identifier>IR</Identifier>
        <Timestamp>2017-01-01T02:11:01Z</Timestamp>
    </SourceDetails>
    <AsOfDate>2017-01-02</AsOfDate>
    <Instrument>
        <CommonCode>GB0</CommonCode>
    </Instrument>
    <Rate>0.69</Rate>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An alternate solution using [Diffy](https://github.com/samg/diffy) to do the comparison. It is a flat string comparison but it does have an html formatted output.

```rb
require 'diffy'

puts Diffy::Diff.new('./docOne.xml', './docTwo.xml', :source => 'files').to_s(:html)
```

```html
#Example output
<div class="diff">
  <ul>
    <li class="unchanged"><span>&lt;root&gt;</span></li>
    <li class="del"><del>test</del></li>
    <li class="unchanged"><span>&lt;foo&gt;&lt;/foo&gt;</span></li>
    <li class="ins"><ins>&lt;bar&gt;&lt;/bar&gt;</ins></li>
    <li class="unchanged"><span>&lt;/root&gt;</span></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you. This looks exactly what I am looking for. I am having some trouble using the gem. It does not seem to be picking up differences.  I have installed the gems diffy, rspec and diff-lcs. For me, the puts in your answer retuens:

    <div class="diff"></div>

no matter what xml files I supply as arguments. I also tried storing my xmls in string variables called doc1 and doc2 and I use the line:
puts Diffy::Diff.new(doc1, doc2, :include_plus_and_minus_in_html => true).to_s(:html)
but I got the same result. Do you know what the issue may be?

Comment: Could you provide a light or similar example of your xml documents?

Comment: I added snippets of the two xml files I am trying to compare to my original question. I tried puts Diffy::Diff.new('./doc1', './doc2', :source => 'files').to_s(:html). I also tried storing the above xmls in variables and then used puts Diffy::Diff.new(doc1, doc2, :include_plus_and_minus_in_html => true).to_s(:html) but both returned <div class="diff"></div> indicating there are no differences. I also tried a basic test using the line puts Diffy::Diff.new("Hello how are you", "Hello how are you\nI'm fine\nThat's great\n") but this line returned nothing but the strings are different.

Comment: I think you are giving it an invalid path to your files. It returns an empty diff if both paths are invalid. `puts Diffy::Diff.new('./invalid_path_to_file.xml', 'invalid_path_to_file_2.xml', :source => 'files').to_s(:html)`
<div class="diff"></div>`

Comment: I could not see anything wrong with the file path so as a workaround, I stored the contents of the xml files in 'String' variables and then wrote 'puts Diffy::Diff.new(doc1, doc2, :include_plus_and_minus_in_html => true).to_s(:html)' where doc1 is the contents of the first xml document and doc2 is the contents of the second xml document but that still returned '<div class="diff"></div>'. I also tried 'puts Diffy::Diff.new("Hello how are you", "Hello how are you\nI'm fine\nThat's great\n")' as a simple test to see if it was my xml string causing the problem but this test returned nothing.

Answer (score 1):

There is a [nokogiri-diff gem](https://github.com/postmodern/nokogiri-diff) you can use to do this. It simply finds the differences and returns an `Enumerable` object.

```rb
require 'nokogiri/diff'

xmlDoc1 = File.open("docOne.xml") { |f| Nokogiri::XML(f) }
xmlDoc2 = File.open("docTwo.xml") { |f| Nokogiri::XML(f) }

xmlDoc1.diff(xmlDoc2).each do |diff|
  puts diff
end
```

```
#2nd example
doc1 = Nokogiri::XML("<root><aliens><alien><name>Alf</name></alien></aliens></root>")
doc2 = Nokogiri::XML("<root><alienz><alien><name>Alf</name></alien></alienz></root><test></test>")

xmlDoc1.diff(xmlDoc2).each do |diff|
  puts diff
end
```

```
#2nd example output
<root>
  <aliens>
    <alien>
      <name>Alf</name>
    </alien>
  </aliens>
</root>
-
<aliens>
  <alien>
    <name>Alf</name>
  </alien>
</aliens>
+
<alienz>
  <alien>
    <name>Alf</name>
  </alien>
</alienz>
```

Comment: Hi Macro, thank you very much for your answer. Would you mind explaining the output of the examples? I am unsure of what the plus and minus is referencing to in the second example. I tried the first example to see if that would make it clearer, but it did not as there were a lot of spaces in between the plus and minus symbols.
Also why is <test></test> is not showing up as a difference?
Thank you for your time.

Comment: The `+` represents additions and the `-` represents deletions. Not sure why the `<test>` node is not showing up in the diff.

Comment: Do you know if there is a gem which formats these xnl differences in a html report? I know that when it comes to csv differences there is a gem called csv-diff which gives raw output and csv-diff-report which formats the differences from csv-diff into a html report. Is there a report gem like this for xml differences?

Comment: I added a new answer using the diffy gem.